# Storekit requestProducts returns empty products array, nothing returned invalid

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, appcelerator-mobile, storekit

I am trying to get IAP working with Appcelerator Titanium 3.1. I have all the signing/certificates/provisioning profiles/contracts working. I was getting an invalid product ID, and fixed that issue. Now, the product array is simply returned empty when calling requestProducts().

When I requestProducts('valid_product')

```
Response: {"type":"callback","products":[{}],"source":{},"success":true}
```

When I requestProducts('invalid_product')

```
Response: {"products":[],"type":"callback","source":{},"invalid":["invalid_product"],"success":true}
```

Note that I do not get an invalid product returned when I request a valid product (setup in itunesconnect under IAP for this app), I simply get an empty string for the product array.

Why could this be happening? I have tried this for IAP products in the "Waiting for Review" status, as well as "Ready to Submit" status. I have not yet submitted the binary for review.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Regards,
Daniel

**EDIT, code posted below**

```
function requestProduct(identifier, success) {
showLoading();
Storekit.requestProducts([identifier], function (evt) {
    hideLoading();
    Ti.API.info('ReqProduct:' + JSON.stringify(evt));
    if (!evt.success) {
        alert('ERROR: We failed to talk to Apple!');
    }
    else if (evt.invalid) {
        alert('ERROR: We requested an invalid product!');
    }
    else {
        alert('success. product: ' + JSON.stringify(evt.products[0]));
        success(evt.products[0]);
    }
});
```

}

calling the above function as follows:

```
var product;
requestProduct('22credits', function(data) {
Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(data));
product = data;
});
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: No problem, just edited in some code

Comment: I have that same StoreKit.js file and it works. I would suggest checkin your configurations in order to see the problem but if you say you get no "invalid product" then I don't know what could be the issue here :S

Comment: @Daniel  - did you find a solution for this issue?